# 503 Service Unavailable error in AWS ec2 instance without load balancer

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-503

I'm pretty new to AWS. I have created an instance of ec2 and separate RDS. I have deploy my code. Sometimes I'm getting 503 error Service Unavailable (The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later) from API.
Note1:  I'm not using load balancer.
Note2:  Sometimes I got the my required response (200 status). But most of the time its 503.
How I have to fix that error please?
Help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear. Please provide all relevant information abotu your ec2 and RDS setup, testing procedure and application.

Comment: @Ritesh Yeah I solved it. First I have increase php memory_limit to infinite (-1) and then work on optimization of script that was taking time to get data. It works for me.
Link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72367345/increase-php-memory-limit-in-apache-aws-server-under-ec2-instance

Comment: @TechLeadz thanks for the reply buddy. I'll try this and will post the result for the same.