# Increase PHP memory_limit in apache aws server under ec2 Instance

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to increase my PHP memory_limit in AWS server under ec2 Instance. I updated the script of the file inside /etc/php.ini and increase memory_limit from 128M to -1 but it doesn't affect at all. Both of my local and master limits are still at 128M. Please take a look at screenshot link below:
Link:  https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/27651726?key=7b47c86478c96f1d3543bd56fadcb86b
Help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you restarted the php-fpm service?

Comment: ok thanks. It worked now by restarting php-fpm.
 (sudo systemctl restart php-fpm)